# How to convert currency symbol to Currency Code in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, currency

I need to convert currency symbol such as "$" or "RM" to Currency Code like "USD" and "MYR" in my iOS app.

Comment: There isn't a 1-1 reverse mapping - see [this xe reference](http://www.xe.com/symbols.php), so it would not yield consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSNumberFormatter`

The currency value string is still going to be formatted based on the user's locale

`[numberFormatter setCurrencyCode:@"USD"];`